# Android View animation before API level 11

Tags: android, animation, android-support-library

Is there a way to use View animation methods previous to API 11?  I know about the Support v4 library but I can't figure out how to use it, so I can't tell if a solution is in there.  I want to be able to execute a line like that below in earlier versions:

```
activeAnimator = sliderHolder.Animate().TranslationX(newX).SetDuration(500).SetListener(new SlideFinishListener(this));
```

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [NineOldAndroids](http://nineoldandroids.com/), which provides all of the same functionality and API that the HoneyComb+ APIs do.